# windows shell - how to detect the current location where script file is placed?

Tags: windows, vbscript, windows-shell

I am trying the windows shell file which will be inserted in the folder where it will analyze folders content.

Now i would like to know how can i detect which is the current path ? i.e. location where the vbs file is placed using FileSystemObject?

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
WScript.Echo objFS.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get that from [`WScript.ScriptFullName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc5ywscw(VS.85).aspx). Just remove the filename from the end (the bit after the last backslash). I normally use JScript for scripts, but IIRC VBScript has an `InStrRev` function that will help you find the last backslash. Or: Create a `File` object for the `WScript.ScriptFullName` path and then use its [`ParentFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dt64ftxb(VS.85).aspx) property. Something like (untested):

```
Dim objFSO
Dim objFile
Dim objFolder

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(WScript.ScriptFullName)
Set objFolder = objFile.ParentFolder
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the full path only without the extension I use `Replace(WScript.ScriptFullName, WScript.ScriptName, "")` to just result in a filepath